# Why Dictionary<T, V> explicitly implements ICollection<KeyValuePair<T, V>> when it is already inherited by IDictionary<T,V>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Recently I've been asked by my friend why `Dictionary<T, V>` explicitly implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<T, V>>` when it is already inherited by `IDictionary<T,V>`?

I realized that I don't know the answer as well. Here are the links to official documentation:

`Dictionary<T, V>` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx
`IDictionary<T,V>` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx

Is there any specific reason why it was done like that? Is there a specific architecture pattern or anything?

Comment: You can't see that from the documentation - it shows all interfaces, no matter how they were implemented.

Comment: If you're talking about the explicitly implemented methods, those are explicit to avoid showing them on the class itself, not because of any relation to `IDictionary`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I take a look at the source code after your comment.but it's the same as the documentation.

Comment: @Selman22 Are you referring to explicitly listing the interface to derive from, or about explicitly implemented interface methods? If the interface is listed in the IL and thus seen in a decompiler that can be an artifact of how CIL and the C# compiler work. If it's in the ROTOR source, then it's a stylistic choice by Microsoft which has no impact on the compiled program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to simply be a case of showing all of the implemented interfaces implicitly.

I made this following example to test this. My source code is:

```
public class Class1 : ITest
{
    public void Testing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }

    public void Testing2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test2");
    }
}

public interface ITest : ITest2
{
    void Testing();
}

public interface ITest2
{
    void Testing2();
}
```

Now going in to Reflector.Net and decompiling I get this:

```
public class Class1 : ITest, ITest2
{
    public void Testing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }

    public void Testing2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test2");
    }
}
```